# Two VPCs which are peered, need to get traffic to VPC B from a device at the other end of the VPN connection

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

AWS networking question - I have 2 VPCs (A & B) which are peered. I have a Site to Site connected to  VPC A. I need to get traffic to VPC B from a device at the other end of the VPN connection.
As you cannot jump across VPC's I'm thinking something like an Nginx proxy on VPC A which is the endpoint the device will forward traffic to, and then the traffic will be pushed onto the final endpoint in VPC B.
Can anyone else think of any other solutions? I cannot put the VPN in VPC B due to compliance issues.

Comment: Depending on what kind of traffic you mean, have you considered AWS PrivateLink? https://aws.amazon.com/privatelink/?privatelink-blogs.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&privatelink-blogs.sort-order=desc

Answer (score 1):

Please use below approach.
1)Use the Transit Gateway which will scale as you add multiple vpcs.
2)Use ELB in vpc A and target server could be in vpc B.